# Laravel Listener to clear Session on logout is not working

Tags: laravel, session, events, listener

I want to put a Listener in my Laravel project which listens for the user logging out and fires and event then, for an example a redirect or clearing the session.

I have this code which I added to the EventServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
        'App\Listeners\Logout' => [
            'App\Listeners\ClearSessionAfterUserLogout'
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);
    }
}
```

Then, I have following code put inside my app/Listeners/ClearSessionAfterUserLogout:

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;
use Session;
use App\Classes\Helper;

class ClearSessionAfterUserLogout{
    public function handle(Logout $event){
        Session::flush();
        Session::set('configuration', NULL);
        Helper::unloadConfiguration();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
?>
```

Nothing I put inside my ClearSessionAfterUserLogout seems to be working. The function "unloadConfiguration()" I know for a fact works, because I use it in other places. (It simply clears a specified Session variable). Flushing the session does nothing either. Because when I login with another account, some content is STILL loaded based on what was in the session for the previous account.

So my question: How do I clear all session data when the user logs out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Laravel fires a `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` event, so you should listen for it instead:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
        'App\Listeners\ClearSessionAfterUserLogout',
    ],
];
```

Comment: this gives me the following error when I logout: FatalThrowableError in ClearSessionAfterUserLogout.php line 8:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\ClearSessionAfterUserLogout::handle() must be an instance of App\Listeners\Logout, instance of Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout given

Comment: Remove `Logout $event` as a paremeter in your **handle()** method. It should be like this `public function handle(){`.